# How do you configure Jenkins to use git archive instead of git clone with Gerrit?

Tags: git, jenkins, gerrit

We have an automated build system configured using Jenkins, integrate with Gerrit. One of the bottlenecks today is that it takes ~3.5 minutes for Jenkins to complete a "git clone" for each build, due to repository size. The same check-out using "git archive" takes approx 12 seconds.

Can the gerrit plugin for Jenkins be configured to use "git archive"? This will significantly reduce our build time.

Comment: A quick scan of the git plugin source code says "no", since I believe it's what does the cloning, rather than the Gerrit Trigger plugin. However, possibly of benefit is the git plugin's "Fast remote polling" option (under Advanced) -- though I'm not sure if that saves you an initial clone.

Comment: As far as I know the common git plugin only `pull` changes. A complete clone seems just oversized. However, even for a clone 3 minutes seems too much. Make sure you don't use `http:` as protocol (and such)

Comment: It currently does a clone for each checkout - 3 minutes seems like a long time but it's > 5 years of history in the repository and 300+ MB per checkout.

Comment: Do you really need a new clone for each build? Or does Jenkins clone and you just don't know why? We also use Jenkins and Gerrit and Jenkins just fetches the change from Gerrit, and doesn't clone the whole repository.

Comment: No - I do not need a clone or any Git history at all (see my answer below). Jenkins does a clone and I did not know why, although it appears to be part of the Git SCM plugin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although it doesn't appear to be possible using an unmodified version of the Git plugin, I did accomplish this in two steps:

```
1) Change SCM to "None" for the particular job.
2) Add a build step at the beginning to checkout using "git archive"
```

Here is a sample for step 2).

```
git archive --format=tar --remote=git://host/repo ${GERRIT_REFSPEC} > ${BUILD_ID}.tar && tar xvf ${BUILD_ID}.tar && rm ${BUILD_ID}.tar
```

Comment: But this means we can't use SCM polling. Any alternative?